# Unity3D Guardar y establecer la posición de un objeto C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño proyecto en Unity3D.
Tengo un objeto (una puerta) que contiene una script en C# con el nombre de la escena a la que quiero acceder. Una vez cambio de escena tengo otro objeto con la misma script para volver hacia la puerta con la que he colisionado, pero lo que no consigo hacer es almacenar la posición donde se encuentra esa puerta (el personaje regresa a la posición inicial que tenía asignado) El código que tengo de momento es el siguiente:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class movimientos : MonoBehaviour {

    public string escena; //almacenamos un objeto como la escena que vamos a cargar, hay mas de 1
    public bool trigger;

    void Start(){

    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {


        if (other.tag == "Player") {

            trigger = true; //Si el Player ha entrado devuelve verdadero en la variable que comprueba

            }
        }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other){

        if (other.tag == "Player") { //Si el Player ha salido devuelve falso en la variable que comprueba

            trigger = false;

        }
    }

    void Update(){

    }

    void OnGUI(){
        if (trigger) {
            GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 60, 200, 25), "Presiona K"); //Muestra por pantalla cuando estemos en el Trigger este mensaje en una posición
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K)){ //Si está dentro del Trigger y pulsa la letra K
                SceneManager.LoadScene(escena); //Cargamos la escena con la propiedad .name

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que podáis ayudarme. Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Alvaro Lechuga  has adjuntado las escenas a tu codigo dandoles un index  en tu files.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando cargas una escena de este modo:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(escena);
```

Se supone por defecto el segundo parametro como **LoadSceneMode.Single**. Esto lo que hace es descargar TODAS las escenas que tengas cargadas, y luego carga la indicada.

Por lo tanto, como respuesta inicial seria NO, no puedes posicionar el personaje en otro punto, ya que estará definido la posicion en tu escena.

Sin embargo, puedes jugar con el **LoadSceneMode.Additive**, que te permite "añadir" la nueva escena a tu juego. Se utiliza mucho si tienes varias escenas (por ej, un pasillo de una casa) y cada vez que entras en una puerta, CARGAS la escena del otro lado.

Puede que te valga algo como:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(escena, SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sabes que es posible realizar este cambio, pero para ello necesitar hacer tres cosas super importantes. La primera es crear un Transfor publico en tu script de personaje, segundo crear un objeto, ubicarlo en la posición donde deseas retornar a la escena y luego arrastrarlo en el Transform publico que creaste con el script dentro del personaje, la segunda es hacer una comparación usando la condición if, esto te permitira saber si ya regresaste a la primera escena. Todo esto lo debes hacer en el **void Star** **esto es super importante** te dejo un ejemplo, pero si no le entiendes bien puedes volver a escribir para dar mas detalles:

```
public class PersonajePrin : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform posiBibli; // creación del transform publico para ubicar el objeto de 
                               posición
    void Start()
    {
// comparación de si ya regrese a mi primera escena comparando los objetos creados en ella
        
if (GameObject.Find("collar") && GameObject.Find("Carlos"))
        {
            transform.position = posiBibli.position;
    }
```

Espero te sirva y como te digo si esta muy confuso no dudes en decirme para poder explicarte de mejor manera.
Acabo de descubrir esto, pues ahora estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto jejejeje